# How to render the entire URL for a link with Jinja (for use in an email)

Tags: flask, jinja2

When creating a link in HTML on a website we typically just use the relative link, such as `/my/link`, and then the web browser fills in root when the page is loaded.  i.e. the browser converts that link into `http://example.com/my/link`.  This is great in general, but I'm using jinja2 to render an email body (using `render_template`), so the HTML content is never displayed under example.com, it's only displayed in the email application.  So is there a way for jinja2 to recognize the domain that the app is on and tell `render_template` to fill in the entire link?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `_external` flag to `True` to force a full URL to be generated:

```
url_for(endpoint, _external=True)
```

See the [`flask.url_for()` documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for):

> **_external** – if set to *True*, an absolute URL is generated. Server address can be changed via *SERVER_NAME* configuration variable which defaults to *localhost*.